# Как заменить NaN в серии Pandas с помощью словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть DataFrame:

```
    Customer    City
0   Customer 1  Moscow
1   Customer 1  Moscow
2   Customer 1  Moscow
3   Customer 1  NaN
4   Customer 2  New York
5   Customer 2  New York
6   Customer 2  New York
7   Customer 2  NaN
8   Customer 2  NaN
9   Customer 2  NaN
10  Customer 2  NaN
11  Customer 2  NaN
12  Customer 3  London
13  Customer 3  London
14  Customer 3  London
15  Customer 3  NaN
16  Customer 4  Paris
17  Customer 5  NaN
18  Customer 5  Deli
```

И есть словарь:

```
{'Customer 1': 'Moscow',
 'Customer 2': 'New York',
 'Customer 3': 'London',
 'Customer 4': 'Paris',
 'Customer 5': 'Deli'}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заменить 'NaN' в DataFrame на соответствующие значения в словаре по Customer? Я пробовал через метод loc получать доступ к пустым значениям и выполнять replacе по данному словарю, но такой алгоритм берет первое значение City из словаря и заменяет все 'NaN' на него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

словарь замены:

```
mapping = {
 'Customer 1': 'Moscow',
 'Customer 2': 'New York',
 'Customer 3': 'London',
 'Customer 4': 'Paris',
 'Customer 5': 'Deli'}
```

маска замены (учитывает варианты когда `NaN` - это `np.NaN` или просто строка `"NaN"`):

```
mask = df['City'].astype('str').isin(['NaN','nan'])
```

замена:

```
df.loc[mask, 'City'] = df.loc[mask, 'Customer'].map(mapping)
```

результат:

```
In [160]: df
Out[160]:
      Customer      City
0   Customer 1    Moscow
1   Customer 1    Moscow
2   Customer 1    Moscow
3   Customer 1    Moscow
4   Customer 2  New York
5   Customer 2  New York
6   Customer 2  New York
7   Customer 2  New York
8   Customer 2  New York
9   Customer 2  New York
10  Customer 2  New York
11  Customer 2  New York
12  Customer 3    London
13  Customer 3    London
14  Customer 3    London
15  Customer 3    London
16  Customer 4     Paris
17  Customer 5      Deli
18  Customer 5      Deli
```

---

вот более идиоматический вариант заполнения отсутствующих значений в группе *соседними значениями* (не требует словаря замены):

```
df['City'] = df.groupby('Customer')['City'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: Идиоматический вариант не подойдет, потому что в реальном наборе данных города не уникальны для каждого кастомера. И там где пропуски в городах я ставлю штаб-квартиру кастомеру в поле сити. Раньше я джойнил таблицу-словарь к датафрейму и лямбда-функцией проставлял штаб-квартиру, но это очень громоздко. Ваше первое решение, на мой взгляд, оптимально!

Comment: @DenisNovik, это я такой вывод сделал на основании данных из примера. Второй вариант убирать не буду - вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится ;)

Comment: разумеется :)! В любом случае, вы очень помогли. Спасибо!

Comment: @DenisNovik, пожалуйста :)