# Как сделать векторное вычисления в Pandas и создать новый столбец?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Мне нужно получить минимум по каждой строке и только из столбцов у которых в названии стоит `1`, но чтобы он превышал пороговое значение указанное в столбце `max_noise`.

Вот код создающий мой пример демо-матрицы.

```
x = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5],  [7,1,3,6,7,9])
df = pd.DataFrame({
       "A": x**2+8,
       "B": x*9, 
       "C": x+24, 
       "D": (x*x)+3, 
       "E": (x*2)+5, 
       "F": (3**x-x), 
       'idx':[1,0,1,8,2,1]})
df.columns = df.pop('idx')
df['max_noise'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != (1)].max(axis=1)
df
```

Получить столбцы с названием `1` я могу вот таким способом:
`df.loc[:, (df.columns == 1 | 0) ]`
Но как применить функцию `min()` с условием не могу догадаться.

Вот скрин, что я хочу получить в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вам уже советовал использовать уникальные имена столбцов и значения индексов. Решение, скорее всего, будет громоздким и неэффективным просто потому, что придется везде обходить эти "грабли"...

Comment: @MaxU, мне нужно использовать какие-то метки. В данном случае `1` обозначает принадлежность конкретного вектора к какому-то кластеру. Но вполне можно добавить какой-нибудь суффикс для уникализации (например `1_a, 1_b, 1_c ...`), или может быть мультииндекс использовать.

Comment: метки можно хранить отдельно от наименований столбцов. Можно использовать маски и т.д.

Comment: @MaxU, я не знаком с масками. Можете показать пример?

Comment: [пример использования маски для индекса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943853/211923)... В вашем случае маска будет тспользоваться для столбцов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [281]: x = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:, df.columns == 1].values)

In [282]: x
Out[282]:
    0   1    2
0   9  25    2
1  24  28   77
2  17  27   24
3  12  26    7
4   9  25    2
5  33  29  238

In [283]: df['porog'] = (x[x.gt(df['max_noise'].values, axis=0)]
                          .min(axis=1)
                          .fillna(0)
                          .astype('int')
                          .values)

In [284]: df
Out[284]:
idx   1   0   1   8   2    1  max_noise  porog
7     9   9  25   4   7    2          9     25
1    24  36  28  19  13   77         36     77
3    17  27  27  12  11   24         27      0
6    12  18  26   7   9    7         18     26
7     9   9  25   4   7    2          9     25
9    33  45  29  28  15  238         45    238
```

Comment: никак не могу воспользоваться функцией `(x[x.gt(df['max_noise'].values, axis=0)]
                          .min(axis=1)
                          .fillna(0)
                          .astype('int')
                          .values)` съедает всю память

Comment: @Mavar, это последствия обхода "граблей" о которых я говорил в комментариях...

Comment: Если переименовать столбцы например по маске  `1_a, 1_b, 1_c ... ` это поможет?

Comment: попробуйте создать DataFrame с уникальными именами столбцов и уникальными значениями индекса.